# resume vs job application questions

Tags: applications

I filled out a job application, and it says to list relevant work experiences. On my resume, I submitted more work experiences than I listed on the job application "work experience" section, because I've been taught that a resume is a branding document, so I felt like listing more jobs that might not have been so relevant. I got the job but feel weird that my resume and "work experience" on the job application didn't have the same amount of jobs listed. Is it OK that I listed more jobs on my resume than the "work experience" section on the job application? I'm looking to learn more tactics to apply to future jobs. Thanks.

Comment: [Listing short but relevant work experience on resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/43317/25792), [Irrelevant jobs vs long employment gap](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/44421/25792), [How to determine if a job is relevant work experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/125713/25792), [Is it OK to leave very short-term employment off my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9965/25792), [Job application asks to list relevant experience](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/122556/25792), etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it OK that I listed more jobs on my resume than the "work
>   experience" section on the job application?

Yes, it's okay.

You were asked to list "relevant" experiences on the job application. Hopefully, that is what you did.

On your resume, you can list all of your experience, if you choose.